# Require TextBox depending on RadioButtonList selection in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a repeater with a RadioButtonList and TextBox inside. I want the TextBox to be required only if the RadioButtonList has a value of 1 or 2. How can I achieve this?

I thought I could initially enable the RFV on a selected index change but it can't see the items since it is within a repeater. Do I need to do this within the ItemDataBound?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterSurvey" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="form-group">
         <asp:Label ID="labelQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question")%>' />
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV1" CssClass="required" runat="server" 
          ErrorMessage="Required" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="surveyList" />

         <asp:RadioButtonList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ID="surveyList" AutoPostBack="true"
          OnSelectedIndexChanged="surveyList_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Strongly Disagree</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Disagree</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Agree</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">Strongly Agree</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">N/A</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenfieldID" Value='<%# Eval("ID")%>' runat="server" />
         <asp:TextBox ID="textboxComment" Placeholder="Comments" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine"
          Rows="3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV2" Enabled="false" CssClass="required" runat="server"
          ErrorMessage="Comment Required" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="textboxComment" />
      </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Codebehind

```
protected void surveyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (surveyList.SelectedValue == "1" || surveyList.SelectedValue == "2")
   {
      RFV2.Enabled = true;
   }
   else
   {
      RFV2.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: On the first or subsequent times?  Make sure you add the converse of: 

`else
{
   commentRFV.Enabled = false;
}`

Comment: the `sender` should be the RadioButtonList so you can check the values there.  You should also be able to locate `RFV` via the NamingContainer of the RadioButtonList.

Comment: @BrianMains I'm not sure what you are asking, I just want the RFV2 to be enabled when the RadioButtonList is set to 1 or 2 for each instance in the repeater.

Comment: @stephen.vakil I was able to get the RadioButtonList value like you said from the `sender` using: `string value = ((RadioButtonList)sender).SelectedValue;` but could you explain more on locating the `RFV`?

Comment: `((RadioButtonList)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("RFV2")` should locate your validator, I think.  It's basically saying to the radiobuttonlist, "who is in charge of keeping track of control names in my scope?" and then getting that thing, and asking it to find your control.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comment section (stephen.vakil) I was able to create a solution to my problem:

```
protected void surveyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
            RadioButtonList surveyList = (RadioButtonList)sender;
            string value = surveyList.SelectedValue;
            RepeaterItem row = (RepeaterItem)surveyList.NamingContainer;

            if (value == "1" || value == "2")
            {
                ((RequiredFieldValidator)row.FindControl("RFV2")).Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ((RequiredFieldValidator)row.FindControl("RFV2")).Enabled = false;
            }
    }
```